# Java 9 Static Initializers in interfaces

Tags: java, oracle, interface, static, initializer

When Java 8 came out, I was disappointed to see that they still didn't allow static initializers in interfaces. I guess the justification was that it was effectively like adding a private static method to the interface, which in Java 8 was not allowed (since they all had to be public).

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072872

However in Java 9, we are slated to get private static interface methods. Can anyone think of a reason why this change shoudn't/wouldn't include the ability to add static initializers to interfaces?

In Java 8, we have a scenario like this:

```
public interface TestStatic
{
  int NUM=initNum();

  static               //Not legal in Java 8
  {
    NUM=1;
  }

  static int initNum() //Legal in Java 8
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

So if I am allowed to make `initNum()` private in Java 9, then wouldn't is also make sense to allow for static initializers?

I'm not on the Oracle Java team, but I'm hoping that someone at Oracle sees this and can address this question.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based. Whether it makes sense (or not) is opinion.

Comment: Kind of joke *Oracle sees*?

Comment: It's a very interesting question, but a bit of experimentation shows that a `private static` interface method is not the same as a static initializer. If you remove the lines in your code that are not legal in Java 8, add `System.out.println("Hello World");` to the method `initNum` and then write a `main` method with the single line `TestStatic testStatic = new TestStatic() {};`, you will find that `Hello World` is **not** printed. `initNum` is not invoked until `NUM` is used.

Comment: this is a good question. and i bet they have good reasons. you can always raise the question on their mailing list.